# Can gamma rays be blocked or redirected by magnetic or electromagnetic fields?

Tags: radiation, fusion, gamma-rays

I've been interested in fusion research for a while now and found that reactions such as the proton-proton cycle produce a lot of gamma rays which require large quantities of water or lead to shield the outside of the reactor from this harmful radiation.

I was just wondering if magnetic or electromagnetic fields of reasonable magnitude can block or redirect gamma rays instead of using large quantities of water or lead. Is it possible?

Comment: Photons of any energy are not diverted by magnetic fields. Photon-photon processes are not efficient at all. So, no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically no, they are not electrically charged nor have internal dipoles you can manipulate through electrical or magnetic fields.